# Flyway scripts failing with two schema_version tables in a single schema[Resolved ]

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, microservices, flyway

I have two micro services (Consider A and B) are using same database schema with separate schema version tables schema_version_a ,schema_version_b.

Whenever microservice A is creating schema_version_a and executing flyway secripts successfully , microservice B is failing and vice versa.

As I am using flyway 5 schema_version_a table's 1st  entry is

```
1   1.0 init    SQL V1_0__init.sql  -157200059  root    2020-01-06 16:06:41 3905    1
```

which is correct , 
 but for Mircoservice B schema_version_b entry is as per flyway 3.

```
 '1', '1', '<< Flyway Baseline >>', 'BASELINE', '<< Flyway Baseline >>', NULL, 'root', '2020-01-06 16:08:20', '0', '1'
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

Comment: Is really microservice **A** using schema table schema_version_**a** and microservice **B** schema_version_**b** ?

Comment: yes .@Michal . and if i execute microservice B first then schema_version_b is populated correctly and schema_version a fails .

Comment: Using baselineVersion property for flyway resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using baselineVersion property for flyway resolved the issue